# Get output of any layer from a saved Keras model

Tags: python, keras, model, tensorflow2.0

I have a trained a Keras model which looks like the below:

```
train_data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test_data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')  

def build_model(n_rows,n_cols):
        input = Input(shape=(n_cols,n_rows), name='signal')
         
        c1 = Conv1D(200, 5,name = 'conv_1')(input)
        b1 = BatchNormalization(name = 'BN_1')(c1)       
        d1 = Dropout(0.4,name = 'drop_1')(b1)
        c2 = Conv1D(200,5,name = 'conv_2')(d1)
        b2 = BatchNormalization(name = 'BN_2')(c2)
        d2 = Dropout(0.6,name = 'drop_2')(b2)
        c3 = Conv1D(200, 5,name = 'conv_3')(d2)
        b3 = BatchNormalization(name = 'BN_3')(c3)
        d3 = Dropout(0.4,name = 'drop_3')(b3)
        fl = Flatten(name='fl')(d3)
        den1 = Dense(256,name='den1')(fl)
        den = Dense(30,name='flat')(den1)
        
        output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(drp)    
        opt = Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
        auc = tf.keras.metrics.AUC()
        model = Model(inputs=ecg_input, outputs=output, name='model')
        model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy',auc])
        return model
```

I have trained this model and also saved the model using the following code:

```
model = build_model(n_cols,n_rows)
history = model.fit(x = xtrain, y = train)
model.save('model')
```

I want to extract the outputs of the layer named "flat" within the model shown above. Because of memory issue, I cannot train and save my outputs all in one go. therefore I train and save the model, and then try to extract the output from the model by loading the saved model. But I do not know what to do after this?

```
train_data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test_data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
model = load_model('model')
```

How can I used this loaded model to extract output from 'flat' layer for both train_data and test_data?

Comment: I looked at it. There are differences as I am trying to load a completely trained model as compared to the given example where training and getting outputs are done simultaneously. I cannot do that due to a memory issue.

Comment: In terms of code it is the exact same situation, does not matter if you just built the model or loaded it from a file.